# Can't submit or archive my app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I try to archive my app it says

> Command
>   /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool
>   failed with exit code 1

How can I fix this? This never happened before when I submitted my other versions of the app.

I found on SO that I should delete the red files in Compile Sources and Copy Bundle Resources. I did this and it didn't work. (I deleted Launchscreen.xib from there because it was red)

When I try to refresh my account it gives me this:

[image]

I press request and nothing happens.

Comment: If you read the question you would see that I already had tried that just like the guy who answered this question before because it's exactly the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my mac solved this problem for me.